# How to make an api for a python app that is in a continuous loop?

Tags: python, rest, web-scraping, server

I have a python app that calls a recursive method which runs forever. It is a loop that scrapes a webpage and looks for a number and once it finds it, it prints out a message, increments the number, and calls the method again with the incremented number. This goes on forever because the webpage updates itself about once a week and my method prints out the message when that update is caught.

I want to make a mobile app that notifies users when the method prints out a message (ideally within a minute or two of the change). What is the best way to create an api that would allow me to do this? If there is another way, how can i do it?

Comment: Recursive? It sounds more like infinite looping behavior. An application like this seems more suited to a scheduled task, like a cron job instead of a loop. You would be wasting a LOT of CPU cycles polling for something that only changes once a week. How soon do notifications have to go out after the value changes?

Comment: You should be aware that Python has a recursion limit and an iterative approach is generally the better choice than recursion.

Comment: @SteveBoyd i'm very new to python and i hadn't considered that. thanks so much for the information. It would be ideal if the notification went out within a minute or two of the change. i will look into the cron job you mentioned.

Comment: @KlausD. I wasn't aware of that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Using recursive method for infinite loop is a big mistake because every time you call method again the last method goes to stack and if you do it infinite time finally you get stack overflow error. best way for infinite jobs are thread with a simple "while True":

```
import threading

SenderThread = threading.Thread(target=sender)
SenderThread.start()

def sender():
    while True:
        # do your job here
```

**edit:**

according to [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Threading):

> Python threads are used in cases where the execution of a task involves some waiting. One example would be interaction with a service hosted on another computer, such as a webserver. Threading allows python to execute other code while waiting; this is easily simulated with the sleep function.

The reason i used thread is for the main program to do its job or respose to inputs or any thing else that you need.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i understand that the point of threads is to utilize the time when the program is completing a task by starting another task. In my case, are you suggesting to use one thread that continues forever to avoid the problem of stack overflow? Or using multiple threads which begins when one thread ends? I am asking because I am very new to this and confused on how to approach the problem.